# How to loop through several regions of a worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for some VBA that will allow me to loop through several different REGIONS on a worksheet. Not individual cells, necessarily, but to jump from "currentregion" to the next "currentregion". And once the region is located, it should be selected and copied.

I've tried setting a StartCell (via Cells.Find(What:="*") and then using that cell to select the corresponding 'currentregion'. The issue is how to move to the next 'currentregion', until all 'currentregions' on the worksheet have been copied/pasted.

My results are inconsistent so far, where sometimes all the necessary regions are copied/pasted, but other times some of the regions are ignored (same exact worksheet, same exact data).

```
Set StartCell = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)Do

            'Select Range and copy it
              If StartCell <> "" Then
              StartCell.currentregion.CopyPicture

            'Select a cell to paste the picture in
              Range("A16").PasteSpecial

            'Move to next range to be copied

            Set StartCell = StartCell.End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight)
           StartCell.Select
            End If

        Loop Until StartCell = ""
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that we cannot *provide any code* because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. If you show the code you have tried or provide a [mcve] we can help you. Reading [ask] might also help you to improve your question.

Comment: Why are you using `.CopyPicture`? Where do you want the copied information output to?  Right now it's all just being pasted on top of each other as images in cell `A16`...

Comment: Would help your question if you could explain roughly how your "regions" are arranged on the sheet.  All in a row/grid/column?  Randomly?

Comment: All of the existing regions are currently side by side, going horizontally across (output from Biz Objects that way). My manager wants them a) copy/pasted as pictures b) arranged vertically on the spreadsheet. Yes, I know they are all being copied to the same cell. That's because I work in tiny steps, trying to get each "section" of code to work, before moving on to the next. My next step will be to rearrange all of the pasted pics in some organized fashion.

Comment: Also, if my code example above looks like crazy talk, that's because I cobble various things together until something "works". Not the best for efficiency, I know.

Comment: Could you share the layout of your worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ProcessEachRegion()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'define your sheet

    Dim StartCell As Range
    Set StartCell = ws.Range("A1") 'define start cell

    Do Until StartCell.Column = ws.Columns.Count 'loop until end of columns
        With StartCell.CurrentRegion
            'do all your copy stuff here!
            '.Copy
            'Destination.Paste


            Set StartCell = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(ColumnOffset:=.Columns.Count - 1).End(xlToRight)
        End With
    Loop
End Sub
```

It looks for the next region right to the previous one (regions 1 to 5 in the example below).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main sub (I named it `tgr`) will call a function named `GetAllPopulatedCells` which defines a range for all populated cells in a worksheet.  The `.Areas` property will let your loop through each region.  It will then copy each Area/Region as a picture (still not sure why you want this) and put it in the destination cell, and then adjust the destination cell as needed so that all of the pasted images are stacked on top of each other.

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rAllRegions As Range
    Dim rRegion As Range
    Dim rDest As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rAllRegions = GetAllPopulatedCells(ws)
    Set rDest = ws.Range("A16")

    If rAllRegions Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No populated cells found in '" & ws.Name & "'. Exiting Macro.", , "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each rRegion In rAllRegions.Areas
        rRegion.CopyPicture
        rDest.PasteSpecial
        Set rDest = rDest.Offset(rRegion.Rows.Count)
    Next rRegion

End Sub

Public Function GetAllPopulatedCells(Optional ByRef arg_ws As Worksheet) As Range

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rConstants As Range
    Dim rFormulas As Range

    If arg_ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet Else Set ws = arg_ws

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rConstants = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set rFormulas = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case Abs(rConstants Is Nothing) + 2 * Abs(rFormulas Is Nothing)
        Case 0: Set GetAllPopulatedCells = Union(rConstants, rFormulas)
        Case 1: Set GetAllPopulatedCells = rFormulas
        Case 2: Set GetAllPopulatedCells = rConstants
        Case 3: Set GetAllPopulatedCells = Nothing
    End Select

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set rConstants = Nothing
    Set rFormulas = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Believe me, I don't understand why the copy/paste-as-pic, either. I am going to give this a try and see where I end up. I'll report back. Thanks!